# Android ListView BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, mobile, adapter, baseadapter

My Adapter class like this :

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View satirView;
    satirView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter, null);
    TextView ad = (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.ad);

    TextView soyad = (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.soyad);
    TextView tarih = (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.tarih);
    Button buton = (Button) satirView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    police po = policem.get(i);
    ad.setText(po.getAd());
    soyad.setText(po.getNo());
    tarih.setText(po.getTarih());


    return satirView;
}
```

and My mainActivity class like this :

```
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Defined Array values to show in ListView
    List<police> values = new ArrayList<police>();
    values.add(new police("ss","kk","123"));
    values.add(new police("ss","kk","456"));
    values.add(new police("ss","kk","789"));
    values.add(new police("ss","kk","147"));
    values.add(new police("ss","kk","258"));
    values.add(new police("ss","kk","753"));

    adabter adapt = new adabter(this,values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapt);
```

i have button but i can not use onclickedlistener metod.. How should i do ? 
Where i must to write ?

Comment: Where do you want to set the click listener ? on the whole list item or just the button in your view ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to click on button only not in the whole List Item then you just write your Code in adapter class inside getView() method like :

```
buton .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

and if you need click event on whole list Item then you should write code in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
      ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) satirView.getTag();
      holder.buton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

       //do your stuffs here

       }         
    });
```